# Pluggable Spring context files

Tags: java, spring

What would be the best way to handle a situation, where new Spring context is introduced to application during a runtime, and server restart is not an option?

I have an application where some beans are registered to other bean called "manager" when context is created. Now, should there be new functionality needed later, I have a Spring configuration file defining beans for the new functionality, and these beans should register them selves to "manager", which is already created. This works fine if the new file is added to classpath and server is restarted, but how to achieve it without restarting?

I guess I should make Application container somehow notice new context files and process them like during startup. But is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered combining spring with a framework like Apache Felix?

http://felix.apache.org/